# Use predicted probability of one model to train another model and save as one single model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a `XGBoost` model that I am using for some binary classification purpose. It makes use of some features namely `f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7`

I want to make use of another `LogisticRegression` model from `sklearn` that makes use of the output of the model and a feature of `XGBoost` model to make prediction ie it must take `f1, out` to make the prediction. Where `out` is the prediction made by the `XGBoost` model.

I want to save these two model into a single file some how to make prediction in production.

How can I do that.?

Comment: Use Pipeline and FeatureUnion.

Comment: @VivekKumar can you point me to some examples I can refer to.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a combination of [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) and [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) to achieve this.

Something like this:

```
final_classifier = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('f1', FeatureSelector()),
        ('out', XGBoostClassifierTransformer()),
     ])
    ),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression()),
])
```

Here, `FeatureSelector()` and `XGBoostClassifierTransformer()` are custom wrappers that you can easily make on your own. You need to implement the `fit()` and `transform()` methods with the output you want to send to the next part of the pipeline.

FeatureUnion will call `transform()` on each of its internal parts and then combine the outputs. The pipeline will take this output and then send to next part, ie LogisticRegression.

This will look something like this.

```
X --> final_classifier, Pipeline
            |
            |  <== X is passed to FeatureUnion
            \/
      features, FeatureUnion
                      |
                      |  <== X is duplicated and passed to both parts
        ______________|__________________
       |                                 |
       |                                 |                         
       \/                               \/
   f1, FeatureSelector                out, XGBoostClassifierTransformer
           |                                          |   
           |<= Only f1 is selected from X             | <= All features are used in XGBoost
           |                                          |
           \/________________________________________\/
                                      |
                                      |
                                     \/
                                   clf, LogisticRegression
```