# How to compose sklearn estimators using another estimator?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to train a [`LogisticRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) and a [`RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) and combine their scores using a [`GaussianNB`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html):

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)

logit = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
logit.fit(X, y)

randf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=0)
randf.fit(X, y)

X1 = np.transpose([logit.predict_proba(X)[:,0], randf.predict_proba(X)[:,0]])

nb = GaussianNB()
nb.fit(X1, y)
```

How do I do this with [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) so that I can pass it to [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) and [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)?

PS. I suppose I can define my own class implementing the `fit` and `predict_proba` methods, but I thought that there should be a standard way to do it...

Comment: If you want to do blending/stacking should not you use a holdout set, i.e. https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5612AQFXTHbc8IEweg/article-inline_image-shrink_1000_1488/0?e=1548892800&v=beta&t=wgKK2NfaQ8zKXD5lQj4fP8KiMN2wvPOP_cY4wSz4lXY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing inbuilt in sklearn to do what you want without writing some custom code. You can parallelize some parts of your code by using [`FeatureUnion`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html), and sequence the whole task using [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) but you need to write custom transformers which can forward the output of `predict_proba` to `transform` method.

Something like this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)

# This is the custom transformer that will convert 
# predict_proba() to pipeline friendly transform()
class PredictProbaTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, clf=None):
        self.clf = clf

    def fit(self, X, y):
        if self.clf is not None:
            self.clf.fit(X, y)

        return self

    def transform(self, X):

        if self.clf is not None:
            # Drop the 2nd column but keep 2d shape
            # because FeatureUnion wants that 
            return self.clf.predict_proba(X)[:,[0]]

        return X

    # This method is important for correct working of pipeline
    def fit_transform(self, X, y):
        return self.fit(X, y).transform(X)

logit = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
randf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=0)

pipe = Pipeline([
                 ('stack',FeatureUnion([
                              ('logit', PredictProbaTransformer(logit)),
                              ('randf', PredictProbaTransformer(randf)),
                              #You can add more classifiers with custom wrapper like above
                                       ])),
                 ('nb',GaussianNB())])

pipe.fit(X, y)
```

Now you can simply call `pipe.predict()` and all the things will be correctly done.

For more information about FeatureUnion, you can look at my other answer here to a similar question:-

- [Use predicted probability of one model to train another model and save as one single model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837559/use-predicted-probability-of-one-model-to-train-another-model-and-save-as-one-si/52854138#52854138)